# Swift : Sprite Animation Bug

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am getting this error in the debugger :

CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom

Any idea how I can fix this? It seems to only come up the first time the images load up/animate. I notice this because the performance is affected, the character seems to slightly lag and fade in and out.

Here is my code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    setUpDiplo()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    diplo.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1), count: 10))

}

func setUpDiplo(){

    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Diplo")

    for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {

        var name = "Diplo\(i)@3x.png"

        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))

    }
    diplo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Diplo1@3x.png")
    diplo.size = CGSize(width: 971 / 3, height: 1727 / 3)
    diplo.position = CGPoint(x: (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.5, y: (self.view?.bounds.height)! * 0.5)
    self.addChild(diplo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using texture atlas the correct way.  For some reason, you are doubling the size of it, which is most likely going beyond the atlas limitations.

As long as your files are setup correctly (where image, image@2x,and image@3x are in the same directory,) Apple will automatically pick the correct file you need.

Just set your code up like this.

```
func setUpDiplo(){

    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Diplo")

    diplo = SKSpriteNode(texture: textureAtlas.textureNamed("Diplo1"))
    //took out the size unless you need the node to be larger than the texture @1x
    diplo.position = CGPoint(x: (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.5, y: (self.view?.bounds.height)! * 0.5)
    self.addChild(diplo)
}
```

Comment: good catch, forgot to add it in for him,  he wasn't using the atlas to begin with, thats what threw me off

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying... By the way, you need diplo = SKSpriteNode(texture: textureAtlas.textureNamed("Diplo1"))...You can't use subscript syntax on texture atlas instance (which would be handy for sure if it was possible).

Comment: yeah, that's why I have wrapper classes to handle stuff like that lol, thanks again

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your response! I tried this code, but I still received those errors. Should i even use an Atlas?

Comment: yes you should use atlas,  are you getting it in that function?

Comment: did you create the atlas correctly?  in your xcassets folder, make sure that you have a folder inside of it called Diplo.spriteasset (You need to use Finder to check this out) and make sure that Diplo1 has all 3 asset sizes filled in